# Calculation puzzle 010

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

Find the missing number in the sequence.

```
2   9   28   65   ?   217
```

Source: This question is taken from YTU YOS 2018 exam. I have mentioned them in other posts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simply just

> $n^3 + 1$

So

> $1^3 + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2$
> $2^3 + 1 = 8 + 1 = 9$
> $3^3 + 1 = 27 + 1 = 28$
> $4^3 + 1 = 64 + 1 = 65$
> $5^3 + 1 = 125 + 1 = 126$
> $6^3 + 1 = 216 + 1 = 217$

Therefore the missing number is

> **$126$**

Comment: Gz mate nice one

Answer (score 2):

> The answer is 126 because of the pattern 1cubed +1, 2cubed+1, 3 cubed +1,4cubed +1, 5cubed+1,6cubed+1

Comment: By the way I did not copy this answer

Comment: There was no answer as I was typing it

Comment: Don't worry, people will be able to see that you didnt from the timestamp, as you can see we both answered at almost the same time

Comment: Yesterday I answered the question 3 minutes before another guy and he still got the credit I don't have good luck here

Comment: Sometimes a later answer will be accepted if the OP thinks that it's more correct or explains it better, it's not always first to get it is accepted :)

Comment: Ah yeah could be that we got the same answer but his was more detailed in reasoning